# Where is the complete list of GitHub achievements?

Tags: github

GitHub seems to have updated the achievements feature, so what other achievements are there? Is there a list of achievements and their unlock requirements? Didn't find any documentation and post about this.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR:** https://github.com/Schweinepriester/github-profile-achievements#achievements

---

While the [answer by Smitop](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153722) is currently correct, there is official documentation including specifics on how the achievements were/are earned, which presumably will be updated with future additions: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/personalizing-your-profile#displaying-badges-on-your-profile

Also I've created a mirror: https://github.com/Schweinepriester/github-profile-achievements

**Update 2022-06-11**:
Seems like I was wrong with this assumption

> which presumably will be updated with future additions

as they even removed the previous three achievements from the documentation when they [announced new achievements on 2022-06-09](https://github.blog/2022-06-09-introducing-achievements-recognizing-the-many-stages-of-a-developers-coding-journey/). Hence currently primarily [my repo](https://github.com/Schweinepriester/github-profile-achievements) fulfills listing the achievements, including new ones.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a third achievement:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

According to [a GitHub blog post](https://github.blog/2021-04-19-open-source-goes-to-mars/#:%7E:text=Achievements%20include,space), there are currently three:

> Right now, Achievements include the Mars 2020 Helicopter Mission badge, the [Arctic Code Vault](https://archiveprogram.github.com/arctic-vault/) badge, and a badge for sponsoring open source work via [GitHub Sponsors](https://github.com/sponsors). Watch this space!

Answer (score 0):

There is another achievement available:

[image]

It's name is *Pull Shark*:

[image]

There is 6 types of achievements, But earnables, there is only 4 of them:

1. Galaxy Brain (2 accepted answers)
2. Pull Shark (2 pull requests merged)
3. YOLO (Merged pull request without code review)
4. Public Sponsor (Sponsoring open source work via GitHub Sponsors)

And for the *Galaxy Brain* and the *Pull Shark* achievements, there is also tiers:

[image]

Everything is described [here](https://github.com/Schweinepriester/github-profile-achievements#achievements).